# Restore dynamic view state in the fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I add my views programmatically.How i can restore states of my views after the fragment is killed ?

I think it can be done with `onViewStateRestored, but i can not configure it's properly.

How i can do it in a right way?

Comment: first define how to "kill" a Fragment

Comment: simulate it with change orientation screen.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: can i use another way ? like restore views by tag or id ?

Comment: why? why would you need it?

Comment: I receive from server data and init my views with this data.For example if my app crashes i don't want to download my image again.

Comment: so save it on the sd card after downloading

Answer (score 0):

No matter how do you creating views (programmatically or in layout file). Save current fragment state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in  `onCreateView()`.

See the [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) reference for further details.

Comment: but why do we need onViewStateRestore?

Comment: As a documentation says, this method called when all saved state has been restored into the view hierarchy of the fragment. This can be used to do initialization based on saved state that you are letting the view hierarchy track itself, such as whether check box widgets are currently checked.
The point is this method is a callback that tells you that view state restored. If you want save/restore fragment state by yourself use onSaveinstanceState()/onCreateView().